# Docker Stack one static IP address for whole stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, docker-stack, qnap

I have a production environment using Docker on my QNAP, I would like to set up a test environment where I can run experiment out without having to interrupt my production environment. I need to have these containers available to my LAN and would ideally like to have them all use a single IP address rather than NAT or give them each their own individual address (I know how to do that) but I'm not sure how. I've tried playing around with it but I am still new to docker and can't figure it out or know if it even possible. When I have tried the example below only the first container came up for each new IP address

Example...
Notes: QNAP IP address is 192.168.2.2 and that everything in this example uses 192.168.2.4 except the last two containers that are 192.168.2.5 (which could be moved to a new stack if needed) **Not a working example, for demo**

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  pihole: 
    image: pihole/pihole
    container_name: pihole
    environment:
      - TZ=AMERICA/Denver
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      qnet-static:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.4

  ftpd_server:
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd
    container_name: pure-ftpd
    ports:
      - "21:21"
    volumes:
      - "/folder_on_disk/data:/home/username/"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      qnet-static:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.4

  mailserver:
    image: docker.io/mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    ports:
      - "25:25"
    volumes:
      - maildata:/var/mail
    environment:
      - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=1
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_PTRACE
    restart: always
    networks:
      qnet-static:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.4


  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      qnet-static:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.5
  
apigw-tomcat:
    container_name: apigw-tomcat
    build: tomcat/.
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8009:8009"
    networks:
      qnet-static:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.5
    depends_on:
     - mysql

    
networks:
  qnet-static:
    driver: qnet
    ipam:
      driver: qnet
      options:
        iface: "eth0"
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.2.0/23
          gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: "and would ideally like to have them all use a single IP address rather than NAT" What's wrong with the normal Docker NAT-based port publishing? You can NAT them to a specific ip address on your host, so all your services in this stack can have a different ip from other services on the same host.

Comment: I don't think I'm familiar with that, I'm guessing its done by '''-p 192.168.2.4:3306:3306 (CLI version)'''? With this I'm guessing that it doesn't matter that my host IP address is 192.168.2.2.  If this is correct do I still need the '''networks:''' part throughout the YAML, can I set hostname or a MAC address?  Sorry for all the questions, I'm still really new to this